# Angular on IIS causes strange rewrite conditions

Tags: angularjs, mod-rewrite, iis

We are working with angular.js deployed on IIS with the rewrite module installed. We have html5mode enabled as well to eliminate the # from the URL. Upon researching how to handle this we were given the following web.config rules to apply for rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^index\.html" ignoreCase="false"/>
          <action type="None"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="." ignoreCase="false"/>
          <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html"/>
        </rule>

      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Upon testing this we have found some interesting issues where the CSS and JS files are not being loaded from the proper path. Currently our only solution has been to hardcode the entire path to those files in the index.html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

This works, but obviously causes major issues for us when migrating the code across our QA, staging and production environments because we have to edit the file.

We have a base tag as follows:

```
<base href="/jbvdev/" />
```

We have now tested the following ways of referencing the files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css" />
```

And none of them work. The following shows what happens when we use each file in reference to a path for our application. For sake of argument, our paths are as follows:

```
index --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/calendar
documents --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/documents/BC498484
caseNotes --> http://10.34.34.46/jbvdev/casenotes/CV/LA%20/2081/BC498484
```

Our results are as follows:

[image: Test results]

As you can see, we have tried all the possible relative path designations, but we get odd results. It appears as though IIS thinks the index.html file is always in the route of the current path it is trying to display.

How can we make our rules force IIS to understand that index.html is in the root of our application? If we could do that we would overcome this problem. Thanks!